# Programmatically setting default media gallery image for Store View (Magento)

Tags: php, magento

I have a script that adds images to my products. It is used to set the image, small_image and thumbnail. The code works nice for the default view, but when I switch to store view the media gallery is set to "no_image". Causing my product to have no image at all in the frontend.

I tried to reset the store view attributes without success.

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($fileName, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$attributes = $product->setStoreId(1)->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
if (isset($attributes['media_gallery'])) {
    $attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->clearMediaAttribute($product, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'));
}
$product->save();
```

How can I modify the specific store attributes, and reset them to use the parent one?

Thank you.

Comment: I have found the solution. Simpler than I thought:

`foreach($product->getStoreIds() as $storeId) {`
     `$product->load(null);`
     `$product->setStoreId($storeId)->setImage(false);`
     `$product->setStoreId($storeId)->setSmallImage(false);`
     `$product->setStoreId($storeId)->setThumbnail(false);`
     `$product->save();`
   `}`

Comment: this "solution" doesn't work for me!!! i have magento 1.6.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 'simple solution' can be even simpler;

```
foreach($product->getStoreIds() as $storeId) {
    $product->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->setImage(false)
        ->setSmallImage(false)
        ->setThumbnail(false)
        ->save();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work!!! also you cant do this with API (at leas i couldn't). i'm trying to figure this out for the last day. still nothing =/

Comment: @karantan It works well enough for the OP. If it "doesn't work" for you then there must be another reason or a different cause.

Answer (score 2):

ok for those who still have problems i have found sql solution:

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` 
WHERE store_id IN (1,2,3,4)
      and entity_type_id=4 
      and (attribute_id=77 or attribute_id=78 or attribute_id=79);
```

in my case i wanted to restore default picture view form all my store views (ids are 1,2,3,4)

edit: modified SQL as Electric Jesus suggested

Comment: you can modify the `WHERE` part to `WHERE store_id IN (1,2,3,4)`